# OnStart () is called after OnStop() and that is making problems for my aplication

Tags: java, android

First I would like to say that I am sorry for the vague title. I didn't know what else to name this question.

I have 2 activities (ActivityA, ActivityB). In ActivityA I have overridden the `onStop()` function and I change value X in a singleton. When I go to ActivityB and `onStart()` is called I check the value X. The problem is that `onStart()` is called before `onStop()` and the value I check in the `onStart()` function is still the old value before `onStop()` changes it.

I know why `onStart()` is called before `onStop()`. What I am asking you guys is an alternative solution to this problem I am currently having.

I need to save a value in ActivityA before I close it and I need to check for the same value in ActivityB. ActivityB can be accessed from several other activities not just ActivityA. And the otehr activities dont change the value.

**SOLVED**
I changed onStop() to onPause() That worked. Thanks guys!

Comment: Its entirely upto the system to call these methods, better would be to use `onPause();` and `onResume();`

Comment: On pause might be most proper place to implements stuff than OnStop().

Comment: @NunChai Isnt on pause called when a new activity comes in the foreground of the old one? I need onStop because I am leaving the current activity. I will try it right now in any case

Comment: onPause will be called when the activity goes into background.

Comment: do not change `onStop()` to `onPause()`, that's still not the correct way of passing values between activities, see my answer.

Comment: The above is correct, you need to implement message passing or putExtra();

Comment: Instead of just editing the question, try accepting the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

don't use singletons.
Activities have the `Intent` to be used as a communication channel between them.

do like this, in activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("value", 10);
startActivity(i);
```

then in activity B, you do (at any point you want):

```
int value = getIntent.getIntExtra("value", 0);
```

also works for double, string, float, bundle, arrays, etc, as seen [in the docs!](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29)

Comment: I use this all the time! Only difference is that I rely on the good old message passing with objects.

Comment: That's the correct way of passing values between activities.

Comment: I use the singleton because I use that value in the application all the time and I serialize it aswell

Answer (score 0):

Its entirely upto the system to call these methods, better would be to use `onPause();` and `onResume();`

[image]

[See what the Official Docs say here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered -- so the code in these methods should be fairly lightweight.